# How to select all non blank cells and paste in table without overriding existing values

Tags: excel, vba

The following code only references Row 3 and i need to capture all non blank cells in Column A and put the values in a Table on another sheet without overriding the existing values. I have tried to manipulate the code with no luck.

Thanks

```
Sub Add_My_Data()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim strTitle As String
lastrow = Sheets("TableData").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
strTitle = Sheets("NewOrder").Cells(3, 1).Value
With Sheets("TableData")
    .Cells(lastrow, 1).Value = strTitle
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values in NewOrder are not formulae, this one-liner should suffice.

```
With Sheets("NewOrder")
    .Range("A3", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy _
                                        Sheets("TableData").Cells(lastrow, 1)
end with
```

Comment: Works great. But i need to copy from A3 in "NewOrders".

Comment: Edit: copy starting from A3 in "NewOrder"

Comment: Great! Thanks so much. Cheers

Comment: Tried to use formula in another workbook. The pasted column was B  not A (also a table). Made the necessary adjustments to code but the data keeps pasting to column A. Suggestions please.

Comment: Change `Sheets("TableData").Cells(lastrow, 1)` to `Sheets("TableData").Cells(lastrow, 2)`